# How to keep search query in a sharable URL

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, url, web

(Web dev newbie here)

I have created a simple one page React App that has an input form and, after a button click, calls an API and displays the response.

I would like to be able to share an URL that would take people directly to the app and would search automatically.

For instance, a user goes to the app (`http://myapp.com/`) and inputs *sophie* and *20*. He then gets information about that person (a *fetch* is made with this input) -  this is already working. But also, the url changes to something like this:

```
http://myapp.com/person?name=sophie&age=20
```

The user would now be able to share this URL and people would be redirected to the app which would show data about sophie, after calling the api with *sophie* and *20* as input again (without the user having to input anything).

What is the best way for doing this?

Comment: `name=sophie&age=20` is called the query string, you can check in the back-end (front-end is also possible but I don't recommend that since it might expose your API credentials) if the url that was asked by the user contains a query string go on and fetch the data from the api on-the-fly.

Comment: You can access URL Search Params with javascript as well as append as needed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Comment: What kind of router are you using? The router can pass these query string params to the react component. The react component will be responsible to call the search api with these params. Then show the results when the call completes in the app.